# Adding line from one long/lat point to another long/lat point using CartoDB

Tags: carto

I have imported an excel s/sheet into CartoDB.

I have the following columns:

BookingReference  | Long | Lat

I want to see the journey my app users take. As such I want add a line between long lat points for a booking reference.

For example:

```
0001/34458      51.5074 -0.1278
0001/34458      52.8984 -1.2698
0001/34458      53.8008 -1.5491
0001/34459      21.1619 -86.8515
0002/44492      21.1619 -86.8515
0002/44492      51.5074 -0.1278
```

One booking reference might have several long/lat points, others may just have a single one or two+

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the PostGIS ST_MakeLine(geom, geom) function.

You can find here a tutorial about a GPS track where we use it: http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/gps_track.html (search for 'st_makeline' text)

The documentation about the PostGIS function is available here:

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html